# Switch audio output to speakers

Tags: audio, uwp, voip

I work on own specialized VoIP client for W10 mobile & desktop. Basic things work ok.

However I cannot get audio output to speakers on my old Lumia.

```
foreach (var item in (await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(DeviceClass.AudioRender)).Where(i => i.Name.Contains("Speakers")))   
             RendererId = item.Id;
```

There is "Speakers (WaveRT)" in device list so RendererId is valid.

Later application tries to open audio device (WSAPI) with found RendererId. But anyway phone plays to receiver only.

I modified Voip sample app in attempt to reproduce issue - yes, it happens with Voip sample app also.

My collegue confirms he has same problem on his phone.

Is it possible to play audio via speaker for voip app ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Phone devices only, you can use the [AudioRoutingManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.phone.media.devices.audioroutingmanager.aspx) to change the audio output.

```
// to get the audio manager
IsAudioRoutingSupported     = ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent(typeof(PhoneContract).FullName, 1);
if(IsAudioRoutingSupported)
{
    // audio routing is supported, we register for the output change events
    m_audioRoutingManager   = AudioRoutingManager.GetDefault();
    m_audioRoutingManager.AudioEndpointChanged += OnAudioEndpointChanged;
}

// to change to output
m_audioRoutingManager.SetAudioEndpoint(AudioRoutingEndpoint.Speakerphone);
```